# Cursor loop all users all databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

so I'm messing around tyring to code a cursor to loop through all users and drop them for all databases.

this is the code that obviously doesn't work, because i'm cracking my head on the logic to grab each user of each db, and run the command.

may someone point me to the correct patch? if possible don't fix the code, just let mw know what I need to think and the direction.

```
    USE master
GO


DECLARE @Command nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @USER NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET @USER =''''


DECLARE DropCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE name IN ( 'CorruptionChallenge1','indexestudo','indexestudo2')

    OPEN DropCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM DropCursor
    INTO @DBNAME

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT @COMMAND = 'USE ' + @DBNAME + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +''
    EXEC (@Command)

     SELECT @USER += 'DROP USER'+ QUOTENAME(name)
                FROM sys.sysusers 
                WHERE name not in ('guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys','public')
                    AND name not like 'db%' AND NAME NOT LIKE '%#%' 
    PRINT (@USER)
    

    FETCH NEXT FROM DropCursor
    INTO @DBNAME
END
CLOSE DropCursor
DEALLOCATE DropCursor

SELECT *    FROM sys.sysusers 
                WHERE name not in ('guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'sys','public')
                    AND name not like 'db%' AND NAME NOT LIKE '%#%'
```

The @user part is what i can't think of. how can I enter a database, then do a drop user, then next one, next one, then when if finishes, go to the next db?

thanks !

Answer (score 4):

To execute dynamic SQL in another database, prepend USE DATABASE to each batch.  Changes to the database context in a nested batch are reverted at the end of the batch.  eg

```
declare @dbname sysname = 'AdventureWorks2017'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('use ', quotename(@dbname), '; select db_name() dbname , * from sys.database_principals');

exec (@sql);
```